# xamarin forms windows unexpectedly exited

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm using xamarin forms   1.4.4.6329 after my update windows app is exited unexpectedly  what should be the solution
The actual problem is happening when the list view getting populated i cant catch the actual error but all my json data is loading in view model i think the problem is happening inside the view  if any one know how to resolve please help me

Comment: you should first isolate your issue, by removing big chunks of your app. then, if you think you've hit a bug, file a bug report at bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: yes  got it now Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource    this is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class StringToImageConverter : IValueConverter 
{ 
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
{ 
    var filename = (string)value; 
    return ImageSource.FromFile(filename); 
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}}
```

and call it by

```
cell.SetBinding(ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, 
new Binding("IconSource", BindingMode.OneWay, new StringToImageConverter()));
```

i got the code from https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/83094/#Comment_83094